# exec() not working with firefox

Tags: c, firefox, exec, fork, argv

I've been using a combination of `fork()` and `exec()` to execute some external command on linux, however, the code seems to fail whenever I try to execute `/usr/bin/firefox` which is a symbolic link to a real binary.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I've tested with other programs (which really are executable binaries and not symlinks to them) and it works.

Here's the code from the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pid_t pid;
  // this was the old line:
  // char *parmList[] = {"", "index.html", NULL};
  // and this is the one that solves the problem:
  char *parmList[] = {"firefox", "index.html", NULL};
  int a;

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    perror("fork failed");

  if (pid == 0) {
    a = execvp("/usr/bin/firefox", parmList);
    fprintf(stdout, "execvp() returned %d\n", a);
    fprintf(stdout, "errno: %s (%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
  }
  else {
    waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I updated the code to include the answer and changed the topic's title because the problem really didn't seem to be due to symbolic links at all. Thanks everyone.

Comment: This seems to work for me both with firefox already running and firefox closed, as you pasted it. If firefox is already open it opens a new tab. Do you have any other error details at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to fail"?

Comment: I simply can't get it to work, I just don't really know what is wrong :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add some code right after the `execvp` to output some diagnostic (i.e. check `errno`, print something *meaningful* ;)).

You could also try to analyze it w/o source modification using [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) or `gdb` for that matter.

See also: [`execve`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execve.html).

**Update as follow-up from the comments**
Firefox is not happy with `argv[0]` being empty, which is what `argList` looked like, unfortunately.

*Lessons learned: Be thoroughly aware of what you pass as `argv` to the program you execute.* :)

Comment: I added a simple check after execvp (and it did not return -1, which means it worked) and errno (which was set to 0). It looks like it is executing the symlink but not opening firefox :\

Comment: After execvp, when it worked, you are executing **something else**... execvp is *no* fork.

Comment: Right, sorry about that.. Anyway, I just added a check inside the child and when it fails, execvp returns -1 and errno is set to something other than 0 (I made the app fail on purpose and errors were reported). With firefox, however, it never gets to the diagnostic part, much like what happens when it succeeds, only it does not open firefox at all (no tab, no window)

Comment: Sounds like your firefox doesn't start ;).

Comment: Well... check if there are still instances running (but not correctly anymore...), try start it from a console to see it's output. Try safe-mode (i.e. disable extensions). Just some hints to get you started ;)

Comment: i fiddled around a little bit and it seems the first string in parmList mustn't be "". Well then, thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Does Firefox insist on having a non-empty `argv[0]`?  You should normally pass the name of the command (either just "firefox" or "/usr/bin/firefox") to the command, but you are not doing so.

---

*[...going to check the deeper comments above - and it seems this is the correct diagnosis, but 21 minutes or so late...]*

Comment: Yes, that was the problem indeed. I'll update the question with the answer :)

Comment: @pwseo: It is an unusual program that won't work like that; you might care to ask at Mozilla whether Firefox is really intended to 'fail' when it is passed an empty string as argv[0].  It is almost a bug.  None of my programs would formally fail because of that; they would, almost uniformly, report the errors with a program name '`**undefined**`' prefixing them, but I think that's acceptable.  A few look at the value of argv[0] to determine which variant of the program they are; those fall back on a default behaviour if the name (argv[0]) is not recognized.